# Configurable Swatches Thumbnails not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, configuration, color-swatches, thumbnail

I am using `configurable swatches` for a product. I want to configure just like the given link.

[Click to see the product](http://www.onlinecarpets.co.uk/belton-feltback-twist-carpet.html)

But in my case the `thumbnails` are not showing. Every `associated product` have single image. and i have also upload images to the main `configurable product`. the `thumbnails` are showing, but when i give `label` name to images, then `thumbnails` are not showing..
I want the `thumbnails`, and when click on `thumbnail`, it change the `color` in drop down.. 
Any Idea.?

Comment: I see that you have implemented the solution on your site. Can you please post that answer?

Comment: this was a reference site. @MichaelYaeger

Comment: Ok, I must say, this is one of the best Magento themes I've seen!

Comment: yes. i am totally impressed from this theme. also lot of custom work.